# Firefox toolbarbutton initialization event

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

What is the proper method to listen to toolbarbutton initialization (say I want to change the icon depending on the current of the addon)?

Right now I'm just listening to `window.load`, and detecting if the toolbarbutton exists via `document.getElementById`.

For user toolbar customizations I'm using the `aftercustomization` event in case the toolbarbutton is removed then re-added by the user.

But is there a more direct method?

Comment: What do you mean by "initialization" event? The toolbar button is there as soon as the DOM is initialized... It might just not be accessible with the "regular" DOM API, as it is hidden in the palette, when the user did not add it to her toolbar (yet). Are you looking for obtaining a reference to your toolbarbutton DOM element always? Or ways to update some properties of the toolbarbutton, no matter if it is in the toolbar or invisible (in the palette)?

Comment: Ah I did not realize that I could get a reference to the invisible toolbarbutton. How would you do that (get the DOM reference)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to "modify" a toolbar button, even if it is hidden away in the palette (the user didn't yet add it, or removed it). Here is a selection:

You may get a reference to the DOM node anyway, by searching the palette manually if `document.getElementById` does not yield a result. This works for browser.xul, anyway. Some code (simplied from code I'm using, but untested after some cleanup). It uses [`<toolbox>.palette`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/toolbox#p-palette)

```
function findToolbarButtonAnyway(id) {
  let tb = document.getElementById(id);
  if (tb) {
    return tb;
  }
  let palette = $("navigator-toolbox").palette;
  for (let c = palette.firstChild; c; c = c.nextSibling) {
    if (c.id == id) {
      return c;
    }
  }
  return null; // not found
}
```

You may instead use [`<broadcaster>` (or `<command>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Tutorial/Broadcasters_and_Observers) to "broadcast" a set of attributes all other nodesobserving the broadcaster will take. You may e.g. set attributes and have corresponding CSS rules to select an appropriate icon or whatever. This solution would be cleaner, but takes some time to figure out.