# Changing Firefox extension icon programmatically

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I am building a Firefox extension which communicates with a web service. In my extension, I am required to change the extension icon in the toolbar based on the login status of the user. Is there a way for me to programmatically access the toolbar icon and then change the image for the toolbar icon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what extensions usually do in such scenario

- If it isn't already, style your [toolbar button with CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/School_tutorial/Adding_Toolbars_and_Toolbar_Buttons#Toolbar_button_icons).
- When the state changes, set or remove some attribute on your toolbar button via `.setAttribute`, e.g. `.setAttribute("loggedin", "true")`. I recently answered a question about dealing with [modifying toolbar buttons no matter if it is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18213548/484441).
- Add new CSS rules defining the style of the button (e.g. a new icon) for when that attribute is set an has a specific value usung regular CSS selectors, e.g. `#xulschoolhello-hello-world-button[loggedin="true"] { /* another icon */ }`